# How can I copy my public ssh key to hundreds of computers without retyping my password hundreds of times?

Tags: shell, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I want to put my public ssh key on hundreds of computers. Usually I just do "ssh-copy-id remoteHost001" and then type in my password. Obviously it's a pain to retype my password a hundred times. What's the easiest way to put my public key on hundreds of computers without wearing my fingers down to nubs?

Comment: How did the same password get onto hundreds of computers?

Comment: @BenVoigt using ActiveDirectory or just domain logging for example.

Comment: @Eugene: If the computers are all members of an AD forest, you can use CIFS to push the `authorized_keys` update, or just host it on a central CIFS server.  But it's really rare to combine ssh and AD.

Comment: @BenVoigt Emm, setting up Windows SSH server to use Windows user database is the natural way. I agree that SSH servers are much more widespread on Unix-like systems but they are used on Windows as well. In any case the question is off-topic for SO.

Comment: @Eugene: If the SSH server is using the Windows SAM, you just stick the public key in an AD attribute and done.

Comment: @BenVoigt it depends on the server software to be able to pick the key. Not all servers do this. Eg. Bitvise SSH server (great server BTW) doesn't seem to support this, yet it's a popular and highly recommended server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ssh commands don't provide command line parameters for passwords to prevent users from hard-scripting their passwords. You can use [this trick](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/) or [this one](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/) to pass the password to the command automatically.